# GH-token is invalid, GitHub Pages Deployment on Travis

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages

I'm trying to set up CI process for my website using Github page,
I followed this guide https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pages/

But looks like it has problem with Github Token.
Here is my repository link: https://github.com/hoanguyen311/vuecommerce

`Preparing deploy
gh-token is invalid. Details: GET https://api.github.com/user: 401 - Bad credentials // See: https://developer.github.com/v3`

Comment: What is `$GITHUB_TOKEN` in your .travis.yml file? Environment variable?

Comment: I've found the problem root cause, that is because I didn't grant enough permission when generating Github token. Now it's ok!

Comment: That's good! You can delete this question then or post an answer and accept it yourself to close this thread.

Comment: I ran in to this error because I was encrypting GITHUB_TOKEN=123thegithubkey with the travis command line tool and then putting that `secure: jumbledmess716230` string under `github_token` in the yaml, rather than just encrypting 123thegithubkey itself. The docs aren't totally clear on it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem root cause, that is because I didn't grant enough permission when generating Github token. Now it's ok!

Comment: What permission did you add? I'm having the same problem, except that it deploys even though it shows the error. The error disappears for a short while after regenerating the token.